# python/kivy - GPS - JVM exception error

Tags: python, gps, jvm, kivy

I am trying to use GPS on android using kivy/plyer and getting an error "JVM exception error"

Screenshot:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5901966/7447369/5413131a-f201-11e4-8792-581ba30c25ff.jpg

Code in method _start:

```
def _start(self):
        # XXX defaults should be configurable by the user, later
        providers = self._location_manager.getProviders(False).toArray()
        for provider in providers:
            self._location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                provider,
                1000,  # minTime, in milliseconds
                1,  # minDistance, in meters
                self._location_listener,
                Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Does somebody know how to get more information about JVM exception?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Was neccesary reinstall python-for-android